# Parse SaveEventually not working IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Im currently developing an application in which the users are offline most of the time, i use parse to save some objects and then send them to parse when online.

im using this code to set up Parse and localstore:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

[ParseCrashReporting enable];
[Parse enableLocalDatastore];
[Parse setApplicationId:@"xxx" clientKey:@"xxx"];

return YES;
}
```

And revising that both crashing reporting and local datastore are available using this code in my first view controller:

```
    NSLog(@"PARSE LOCAL DATA STORE IS AVAILABLE %hhd",[Parse isLocalDatastoreEnabled]);
NSLog(@"IS PARSE CRASHREPORTING AVAILABLE %hhd",[ParseCrashReporting isCrashReportingEnabled]);
```

With this console return

```
2015-01-25 18:03:41.781 ERAVSearca[4311:2274819] PARSE LOCAL DATA STORE IS AVAILABLE 1
2015-01-25 18:03:41.782 ERAVSearca[4311:2274819] IS PARSE CRASHREPORTING AVAILABLE 1
```

So all of this was my investigation to know that the method that is not working is save eventually which i call in this code:

```
PFObject *theObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"ERAV"];

        theObject[@"Piloto"] = facade.ThePilot;
        theObject[@"Copiloto"] = facade.TheCopilot;

        theObject[@"Fecha"] = facade.TheDate;
        theObject[@"Origen"] = facade.TheOrigin;
        theObject[@"Destino"] = facade.TheDestination;
        theObject[@"Matricula"] = facade.TheLicence;
        theObject[@"Hora"] = facade.TheTime;

        //Questions

        theObject[@"Pregunta1"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer1];
        theObject[@"Pregunta2"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer2];
        theObject[@"Pregunta3"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer3];
        theObject[@"Pregunta4"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer4];
        theObject[@"Pregunta5"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer5];
        theObject[@"Pregunta6"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer6];
        theObject[@"Pregunta7"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer7];
        theObject[@"Pregunta8"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer8];
        theObject[@"Pregunta9"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer9];
        theObject[@"Pregunta10"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer10];
        theObject[@"Pregunta11"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer11];
        theObject[@"Pregunta12"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer12];
        theObject[@"Pregunta13"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer13];
        theObject[@"Pregunta14"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer14];
        theObject[@"Pregunta15"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer15];
        theObject[@"Pregunta16"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer16];
        theObject[@"Pregunta17"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer17];
        theObject[@"Pregunta18"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer18];
        theObject[@"Pregunta19"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer19];
        theObject[@"Pregunta20"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer20];
        theObject[@"Pregunta21"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer21];
        theObject[@"Pregunta22"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer22];
        theObject[@"Pregunta23"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer23];
        theObject[@"Pregunta24"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer24];
        theObject[@"Pregunta25"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer25];
        theObject[@"Pregunta26"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer26];
        theObject[@"Pregunta27"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer27];
        theObject[@"Pregunta28"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer28];
        theObject[@"Pregunta29"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer29];
        theObject[@"Pregunta30"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer30];
        theObject[@"Pregunta31"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer31];
        theObject[@"Pregunta32"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer32];
        theObject[@"Pregunta33"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer33];
        theObject[@"Pregunta34"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer34];
        theObject[@"Pregunta35"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer35];
        theObject[@"Pregunta36"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer36];
        theObject[@"Pregunta37"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer37];
        theObject[@"Pregunta38"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer38];
        theObject[@"Pregunta39"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer39];
 [theObject saveEventually];
```

So my question is does anyone know if parse SaveEventually is not working with SDK v 1.6.2? it was working in SDK 1.6.1 for me

Comment: Why are you saving eventually both before and after updating your data?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Throwing an error?

Comment: @picciano no data is sent to parse with or without  internet

Comment: @NicolasCadena There's no guarantee as to when a save eventually object will eventually be saved... So maybe yours just hasn't saved yet...

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-saveeventually-not-saving-eventually-until-after-app-reset

Comment: @LyndseyScott that could be it... any ideas on how to implement save eventually using save in background and pins?

Comment: @LyndseyScott it actually was what you said they saved eventually i dont like this behavior at all but ok thanks!!

Comment: @NicolasCadena Glad you figured it out... Yeah maybe you can do saveInBackground if there's an internet connection and only use saveEventually if there isn't...

Comment: I have noticed that saveEventually does work, but has been taking 10 minutes or more to attempt sending the data AFTER a connection is restored, and only if the app is running. Maybe just wait longer?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is first to saveinbackground if I have connection to internet and saveEventually when there is no connection.

Secondly I encourage my users to save whatever they want without internet but ensure that the last save of the day is done with connection this apparently sends all of the stored data at once.